# A better word for "vaguely insulted"

Tags: single-word-requests

Situation: A character responds in a vaguely insulted, but not offended tone to a question.

I can't think of anything else and vaguely insulted doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: I don't see how you can be insulted without being offended.

Comment: miffed, a good script (scenario) word. punchy. /vaguely insulted tone/ is enough, I'd think.

Comment: a "sigh" works too. 'The mother sighed when her teen daughter accused her of not having a clue'.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like _indignant_? _Miffed_ was the first thing that came to my mind as well, but your situation doesn't actually tell us anything, so it's impossible to do anything but guess. “Vaguely insulted, but not offended” is kind of a contradiction in terms. Could you add what the actual scenario you have in mind is? Or even better, if you can think of a scene from a movie or similar where the kind of expression/reaction you have in mind appears, add a link to that so we can see it being acted out ‘live’.

Comment: Miffed is good.  Peeved is a little more whiny, but might work.

Answer (score 3):

as much questioning as offended .. but might fit what you're looking for

***raise an eyebrow***

> [collins dictionary definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/raise-an-eyebrow)
>
> If something causes you to raise an eyebrow or to raise your eyebrows, it causes you to feel surprised or disapproving.
>
> ⇒ An intriguing item on the news pages caused me to raise an eyebrow over my morning coffee.
>
> ⇒ He raised his eyebrows over some of the suggestions.
>
> ⇒ He was looking at her with his eyebrows raised questioningly.

Comment: I think us Brits need to defend our hard-won reputation for "understatement" here. Raising eyebrows is a bit too explicit for some contexts, where one might simply [***blink** (disapprovingly)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blinked+disapprovingly%22) (whilst maintaining a stiff upper lip, of course! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...haha!